# Warden :renew option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I'm using devise (1.5.3) and warden (1.1.1) and I don't need to renew session_id after user login/registration

https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L160

```
  if opts[:store] != false && opts[:event] != :fetch
    options = env[ENV_SESSION_OPTIONS]
    options[:renew] = true if options
    session_serializer.store(user, scope)
  end
```

Dump options:

```
options {:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :coder=># Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal:0x00000004f50a10>, id=> "56d54b1b9820ee044151fdb4fdcb89db"}
```

How can I configure devise/warden not to set options[:renew] to true ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
env['rack.session.options'][:renew] = false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  auth.env["rack.session.options"][:renew] = false
end
```

Comment: This happens after warden has already renwed the session id. Won't work.